# Why does the this program not work when I add the submit function inside the add function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It works until I add the click function inside the add function.

How to make it work such that when add function is called from within the check function the flag is incremented only when the user clicks the submit button and then the control is passed back to check function so the correct final value should be 3.

```js
var flag = 1;
        
if(flag == 1) {
  $('p').html("xxx");
  check();
}

function check() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    if($("#text").val()=="") {
      alert("Enter some text");
    } else {
      add();
      flag++;
      alert(flag);
    }
  });
}

function add() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    flag++;
    alert("inside add " + flag);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="myform">
  <p id="title"></p>
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: adding a click handler inside a click handler is a code smell. It is almost never what you really want.

Comment: Why do you think you need the `add` function? You already increment the `flag` (in the `else` block) at a click (also the next click). Please explain what the meaning is of `flag`? You never do anything with it, except displaying it in an `alert`. What does it mean when it is, let's say, 10?

Comment: I think you need to add `$( document ).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: Why not `flag += 2;` in the else and remove the `add()` because that is adding a handler for the click event every time you run `add()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$( document ).ready(function() { ... });`

this seems to work as you aspected:

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
            var flag = 1;

            if(flag == 1) {
                $('p').text("xxx");
                check();
            }

            function check() {
                $('#submit').click(function() {
                    if($("#text").val()=="") {
                        alert("Enter some text");
                    } else {
                        add();
                        flag++;
                        alert(flag);
                    }
                });
            }

            function add() {
                $('#submit').click(function() {
                    flag++;
                    alert("inside add " + flag);
                }
            )};
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="myform">
  <p id="title"></p>
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```